# using requirejs without main file nor config()

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs, handlebars.js, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm building an app that will contain many js (jquery) modules (files) using the following setup;

- The build is run using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) task runner.
- I use [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) templates, then generate the html from ***.hbs** files.
- During the build, I [uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) all the js files into one minified file.
- I call the minified file in my application `<script src="assets/js/app.min.js"></script>`

Now, I want to use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) to organize my code and adhere to the AMD specifications..

But I got 3 problems with this approach:

1. I need to have 1 single minified file for all the js; this keeps my code harder to "decode" thus to copy (since it is mixed with other dependencies; jquery, modernizer..) and also helps avoid extra http requests if scripts are called individually.. However, requirejs [needs a main file](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html#add) to initialize the app and inside that main file It calls the other required files.. I don't have such configuration.
2. Many of the dependencies I'm using are in a bower package (that I don't include in the distribution); this makes it not possible to call those files using the [suggested](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#modulename) requirejs method.
3. I'm using jquery on this with some 3rd party plugins that don't call define(); to make them work I have to use [shim config](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#shimconfig) which again rises the problem #2!

So how am I supposed to take advantage of requirejs while keeping my code in modules and well organized?

Sorry for the long question and thanks for reading :)

ps: Feel free to change the title of the question as I couldn't find a better one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally opted for [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) as it adheres to my setup above and allows me to split my app into manageable small modules.

I have also the possibility to use the ease of jQuery (even though it is not a best practice among angular community) and [much more](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/intro).